# How to access a method in fragment class from parent Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am implementing a database as I need to prepare the list or update it everytime I make some changes. I have a fragment on top of mainActivity and I can't perform the operations within the `MainActivity` so some of the operations are to be done in `MainActivity` and others in the `fragment class`.
So in the fragment class which extends fragment has a method called `preparelist()`, which updates the database and populate the data.
In my mainactivity I am performing a delete operations using the default `overflow` menu item, **but here I need to call the `preparelist()` method in order to display the performed operations or the app has to be closed in order to diplay the operation that has been performed**

I have tried the following code which is on the web

```
MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);
( (MyFragment)fragment).prepareList();
```

but this shows error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method...on a null object reference
```

> Basically what I want to know is how do I call the `preparelist()` method within my `MainActivity` without making any other abstract class or anything like that

Comment: You need to create an interface class and via that you need to make changes I feel.

Comment: Why don't you move your delete operations in the fragment class?

Comment: I can't do that as i am using actionbar menu items for this operation @Sufian

Comment: @Keshav1234 isn't there any other way because if i go about making the interface class i will have to change almost half of my code

Comment: If it is a from activity then you can make that method public static otherwise interface is best approach.

Comment: @PiyushGupta ya that i know but here i am working with fragment and the MainActivity

Comment: `prepareList()` is in Activity or fragment?

Comment: it's in fragment class..

Comment: Your problem is in here, i think fragment is null, MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);''

Comment: Then you need to change your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1

Call public method of your `Fragment` from your `Activity`:

```
MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag);
if(fragment != null)
    ( (MyFragment)fragment).prepareList();
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "fragment is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

### Solution 2

Move the functionality of delete to your fragment:

1. move your delete operations in your fragment,
2. in your fragment, write:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
       setHasOptionsMenu(true);        //this fragment can now override
                                   //options menu
   }
   ```
3. now do the same as you do in your activity, overriding the `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, `onOptionsItemSelected` etc. Please note that the method signatures differ to that of `Activity`'s. See [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) documentation.

Comment: Yes the fragment is null... what do i do

Comment: Please update your question with your: **1.**  `onOptionsItemSelected()` of your activity, **2.** `onCreate()` of you activity, **3.** activity's layout xml.

Comment: @Virus if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Sorry but it did not solve my problem yet, i am taking your answer as reference and trying to solve my problem once i solve it i will surely mark it solved

Comment: Thank you i have used the second solution and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Instead, of finding fragment by ID, find it by TAG, for that use need two changes. See below code

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_of_frame_layout_in_xml, myFragment ,"ADD_A_TAG_NAME_HERE");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Replace ADD_A_TAG_NAME_HERE with the TAG name and id_of_frame_layout_in_xml will be the framelayout in xml where you will add/replace your fragment

Now you can find fragment by TAG

```
MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTAG("ADD_A_TAG_NAME_HERE");
```

---

One good way of creating **TAG** is as follows

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String TAG = MyFragment.class.getSimpleName();
...

}
```

So your statement will be like:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.id_of_frame_layout_in_xml, myFragment, MyFragment.TAG);
```

and

```
MyFragment fragment= (MyFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTAG(MyFragment.TAG);
```

Comment: you mean sqlite / database