# sending data from activity to a method implemented in a fragment

Tags: android-activity

I have read through many posts on here with sending data from activity to fragment or should i say invoking a method in main activity that was implemented in fragment class like whhat i have described below. but im looking for another way other than implementing interfaces or putting code in onCreate of the activity or onCreateview of the fragment.
I have this function in a fragment class

```
 public void speaker(String msg){
    tts.speak(msg, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Is it possible to call this function anywhere in the main activity to pass a string value to the function like speaker(text); and how do is this accomplish other than interfaces or putting code in onCreate or onCreateview??

Comment: Check [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29910976/how-to-access-a-method-in-fragment-class-from-parent-activity)

Comment: By researching, I used otto event bus implementation and it works smoothly and is so powerful. Who invented such powerful concept?